# FFMPEG: ‘PIX_FMT_BGR24’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, c, opencv, gcc, ffmpeg

I am building a simple decoding application using FFMPEG API. I know there are solutions available in OpenCV but for specific reason I am refraining myself from using that. Since I am very new to FFMPEG (and to this community as well), I would like to know if there is any mistake that I might have done while building FFMPEG.

**Compiler**: I am using gcc 5.3.0 for compilation and building.

Following are the steps that I followed:

1. I have build FFMPEG library using following configuration:

   > ./configure --prefix=/home/dep/ffmpeg/install/ --pkg-config-flags=--static --enable-gpl --disable-yasm
2. My compiling command is for the application:

   > g++ -std=c++11 -I/home/dep/ffmpeg/install/include/ Queue.cpp Image.cpp CaptureFFMPEGFrame.cpp Object.cpp main.cpp -o main  -L/home/dep/ffmpeg/install/lib -lavutil -lavcodec -lavformat -lavdevice -lavfilter -lswscale -lswresample -lpostproc -lpthread -lz -lrt -llzma -lbz2

The error I am facing is :

```
CaptureFFMPEGFrame.cpp:203:169: error: ‘PIX_FMT_BGR24’ was not declared in this scope
     mpFrameSwsContext = sws_getContext(mpAVCodecContext->width, mpAVCodecContext->height, mpAVCodecContext->pix_fmt, mpAVCodecContext->width, mpAVCodecContext->height, PIX_FMT_BGR24, SWS_BICUBIC, NULL, NULL, NULL)
```

**My effort and understanding:**

1. From my understanding, libavutil/pixfmt.h contains pixel formats which I included along with other includes and the error persists. You can also see libraries I have included along with my application.
2. Since my program is cpp code, therefore my headers are already included using extern "C", i.e. `#include "libavcodec/avcodec.h"`

Anything I might have missed?

Many thanks.

Comment: At some point it was renamed to `AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24`, perhaps it's the problem.

Comment: Oh perfect! That works great, seems like I was following the old documentation (https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/0.5/pixfmt_8h.html)

Comment: Many thanks Roman, new documentation is here for other readers : https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.5/pixfmt_8h.html

Comment: Newest doxygen documentation is always at "trunk", as in:
https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/pixfmt_8h.html
You're linking to the 0.5 and 2.5 release branch documentation. If you're using code from the git master branch (the development branch) then use trunk; otherwise use the same release version number as you are using.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As of commit [78071a14](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/commit/78071a14), pixel formats have been prefixed with `AV_`, and the `PIX_FMT_*` defines were moves to `libavutil/old_pix_fmts.h` (which was included by the original `pixfmt.h`). This file was then removed in the next major version.

The fix (as described in the comments) was just to add this prefix to any `PIX_FMT_*` statements which haven't been updated yet.